# Rails and Devise Behave Differently on 2 servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a development server running OSX, ruby 1.9.3, and using devise 2.2.3.   I have a test server running Ubuntu and is also using devise 2.2.3 but ruby 1.8.7.  Both servers are running webrick for now.  The development server is sqlite3.  The test server is mysql.  I'm having very puzzling behavior with odd login differences in behavior between the two and I don't understand why.

Both servers use the same routes.rb and are using a very simple:

```
devise_for :users
```

On the dev server, if I sign in a new user I am redirected correctly to /main/index via the route

```
root :to => 'main#index'
```

and the new user is successfully logged in.

On the test server, if I sign in a new user I am redirected incorrectly to "/" and I have no idea why, or how to troubleshoot this.   I added this to my ApplicationController but it does not fire:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  redirect_to '/thiswillfail'
end
```

Any suggestions on what might be different on my test server to cause this difference?  I have nothing in routes.rb that points to "/"

edit - I have since found that restarting the test webserver fixes it for a period of time.

Comment: 'For a period of time'. Is the change not permanent?

Comment: I think I was wrong that a server restart fixes it temporarily